# How can I config to access HDFS(namenode HA) with HiveConf class by using hive-common-1.2.1.jar?

Tags: hive, hcatalog, metastore

Who knows why class `HiveConf` has no `HADOOPCONF` enum type in `hive-common jar` now?

I write code using hive-common-1.2.1.jar HiveConf class to access HDFS(HA namenode), and I get an error below.

I realized my code didn't config `HADOOPCONF` so it can't connect to HDFS, but there is no `HADOOPCONF` in hive-common-1.2.1.jar any more, I found previous version of hive-common has the HADOOPCONF.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java.html

My question is how can I config to access HDFS(namenode HA) with HiveConf class by using hive-common-1.2.1.jar?

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:312)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:178)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:665)
```

My code is:

```
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.HADOOPBIN, "/opt/modules/hadoop/bin");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.HADOOPFS, "hdfs://cluster");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.LOCALSCRATCHDIR, "/opt/modules/hive/temp");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.DOWNLOADED_RESOURCES_DIR, "/opt/modules/hive/temp");
hiveConf.setBoolVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVE_SUPPORT_CONCURRENCY, false);
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREWAREHOUSE, "/warehouse");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, "thrift://127.0.0.1:9083");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_CONNECTION_DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORECONNECTURLKEY, "jdbc:mysql://192.168.5.29:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_CONNECTION_USER_NAME, "hive");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREPWD, "123456");
hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVEHISTORYFILELOC, "/opt/modules/hive/temp");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I resolved this issue. 
Because the class HiveConf in hive-common jar load "hdfs-site.xml" from hadoop by default, if only you set the classpath pointed to the folder of "hdfs-site.xml" when you running it.

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/modules/hadoop/conf
$JAVA -cp $CLASSPATH com.baofeng.data.writer.HiveHcatalogWriter
```